# Subdivision of a line into n intervals of linearly changing length

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, data, geometry

This question is separate, but connected to my previous question on this site, that can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186481/linearly-change-the-step-size-in-a-table).

Let's say that we have a line of length X (in this case X=5), defined by a list

```
LineList={{0,0},{5,5}}
```

I would like to divide this line into an arbitrary number of subdivisions, that change in length linearly from one end to the other. I would also like to be able to arbitrarily define the ratio of

```
ratio=(LongestDivision)/(ShortestDivision)>=1
```

So for the simple case of `n=2` and `ratio=2`, you would obtain a list

```
NewLineList={{0,0},{10/3,10/3},{5,5}}
```

Is is possible to apply such an algorithm to an arbitrary parametric curve?

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: It seem that my question was poorly written, so just to clarify, I wish the number of divisions to be independent of the ratio. An example of this would be

`n=4, ratio=10`, which would result in a line divided to 4 subintervals, with their lengths as

`L1:L2:L3:L4=1:3.33:6.67:10`.

For a case of `n=4, ratio=2`, this would produce `L1:L2:L3:L4=1:1.33:1.67:2`.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/generating-evenly-spaced-points-on-a-curve/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  case `ratio!=n` with linear increasing gridsize leads to list of gridpoints

```
x[n_, ratio_] := Accumulate[ Join[{0}, Table[1 + (i - 1)/(n - 1) (ratio - 1), {i, 1, n}]]]  (*//Normalize*)
```

which gives (without normalization...)

```
x[2,4] (*{0, 1, 5}*)
x[3,4](*{0, 1, 11/4, 21/4, 17/2, 25/2}*)
%//Differences
(*{1, 7/4, 5/2, 13/4, 4}*)
```

Comment: While this algorithm does the job for a case where `n=ratio`, I would like to have a more general one, where the `ratio` of the longest section to the shortest section and the number of divisions`n` are not the same. So that on an interval of [0,1], using `n=2` and `ratio=4`, I would get `{0,4/5,1}`. For `n=2` the algorithm is quite simple, but for more than 2 division, I do not know how to handle this.

Comment: So for n=3 and q=4 you would expect `{0,16,20,21}/21`?

Comment: For n=3 and q=4, I would expect `{0,1,3,7}/7`, making it so that the last division is of length 4, the first is of length 1 and all the middle ones are just linearly increasing. So for n=5 and q=4, it would go `{0,1,11/4,21/4,24/4,40/4}/(40/4)`

Comment: Until now the intervalls were decreasing...

Comment: As for the intervals increasing or decreasing, I don't  have a preference. Both versions would be great.

Comment: Your example `n=5,q=4`seems to be wrong: `{0, 1, 11/4, 21/4, 24/4, 40/4}/(40/4) // Differences // N` evaluates to nonmonotonic intervalls `{0.1, 0.175, 0.25, 0.075, 0.4}`

Comment: You are correct. The correct solution should be: `{0,1,11/4,21/4,34/4,50/4}/(50/4)`.
This would then produce the effect that I wish.

Comment: My answer is edited ...

Answer (score 4):

> Is is possible to apply such an algorithm to an arbitrary parametric curve?

Here's a way to plot them:

```
div = #/Last@# &@ Accumulate@ Range[0, 50];
plot = ParametricPlot[{t Cos[4 t], t Sin[5 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> {div}, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

One can get the points with the following; but plotting is not a very accurate solver and the mesh points are generated out of order:

```
pts = Cases[Normal@plot, Point[p_] :> p, Infinity]
```

For a nonsingular parametrization, one can integrate the parameter `t` as a function of arclength.  Then one can get accurate values for the points in order:

```
param = {t Cos[4 t], t Sin[5 t]};
tdom = {0, 2 Pi};
tIF = NDSolveValue[{
    t'[s] == 1/Sqrt[#.#] &[D[param, t] /. t -> t[s]],
    t[0] == First@tdom,
    WhenEvent[t[s] == Last@tdom, "StopIntegration"]},
   t, {s, 0, Infinity}];

pts = param /. t -> tIF@Rescale[div, {0, 1}, First@tIF@"Domain"] // Transpose;

Show[
 plot,
 Graphics[{Orange, PointSize@Large, Point@%}]
 ]
```

[image]

---

*Response to updated Q (as well as some of the comments):*
The OP seems particularly interested in a general way to subdivide an interval `{a, b}` such the lengths of the divisions are in an arithmetic progression specified by the number of subintervals and the ratio of the longest and shortest lengths (the first and last lengths).  One can work out a formula with HS algebra, but one could also leave the work to [`Rescale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html) as above.  One can start from an arithmetic sequence of lengths from `1` to the ratio and generate the subdivision from there:

```
Subdivide[1, r, n - 1] //        (* arithmetic sequence of lengths *)
   Prepend[0] //                 (* prepend zero so Accumulate includes endpoint *)
  Accumulate //                  (* relative divisions *)
 Rescale[#, MinMax@#, {a, b}] &  (* rescale to interval {a, b} *)
```

Compare with `div` and rescaling it to get the second `pts` above.

Here's a function that has a few bells & whistles: It computes either increasing or decreasing lengths; it maintains the precision of the input; it produces a packed array when the input precision is `MachinePrecision`.

```
ClearAll[withWP];
SetAttributes[withWP, HoldRest];
withWP[wp_, code_] :=        (* set up environment for a fixed working precision *)
  Block[{$MinPrecision = wp, $MaxPrecision = wp}, code];

ClearAll[divisions];
divisions[{a_, b_}, r_?(GreaterEqualThan[1]), n_Integer?(GreaterThan[1])] :=  
  withWP[Precision[{a, b, r}],          (* working precision determined by input *)
   Subdivide[N[1, $MaxPrecision], r, n - 1] // (* arithmetic sequence of lengths *)
   Prepend[N[0, $MaxPrecision]] //      (* prepend zero to include endpoint *)
      Accumulate //                         (* relative divisions *)     
     Rescale[#, MinMax@#, {a, b}] & //      (* rescale to interval {a, b} *)
        If[TrueQ[a > b], Reverse, Identity] (* decreasing div. lengths if a > b *)
   ];
```

Examples of `divisions[interval, ratio, n]`:

```
divisions[{a, b}, 2, 2]             (* symbolic subdivision *)
(*  {a, a + 1/3 (-a + b), b}  *)

divisions[{5, 0}, 2, 2]             (* decreasing lengths *)
(*  {0, 10/3, 5}  *)

divisions[{2., 9.}, 2, 4]           (* increasing lengths *)
Ratios@ MinMax@ Differences@ %
#/Min[#] &@ Differences@ %%
(*
  {2., 3.16667, 4.72222, 6.66667, 9.}
  {2.}                                 ratio = 2
  {1., 1.33333, 1.66667, 2.}           OP's L1:L2:L3:L4
*)

divisions[{2., 9.}, 2, 4] // Developer`PackedArrayQ
(*  True  *)

#/Min[#] &@ Differences@ divisions[{2., 9.}, 10, 4]
(*  {1., 4., 7., 10.}  ratio of lengths...
      OP gets L1:L2:L3:L4=1:3.33:6.67:10 but I think this is correct *)
```

If you do the algebra, you can shorten `divisions`:

```
divisions2[{a_, b_}, r_?(GreaterEqualThan[1]), n_Integer?(GreaterThan[1])] :=
  withWP[Precision[{a, b, r}],          (* working precision determined by input *)
   ((n - 1)/(r - 1) - 1/2 + Range[N[0, $MaxPrecision], N[n, $MaxPrecision]])^2 //
         Rescale[#, MinMax@#, {a, b}] & //   (* rescale to interval {a, b} *)
    If[TrueQ[a > b], Reverse, Identity]      (* decreasing div. lengths if a > b *)
   ];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[subDivide]
subDivide = Rationalize[BSplineFunction[#] /@ 
   Normalize[Accumulate@RotateRight@Reverse@Range[0, #2], Max]] &;

subDivide[LineList, 2]
```

> {{0, 0}, {10/3, 10/3}, {5, 5}}

```
subDivide[LineList, 3]
```

> {{0, 0}, {5/2, 5/2}, {25/6, 25/6}, {5, 5}}

```
subDivide[{0, 1}, 10]
```

> {0, 2/11, 19/55, 27/55, 34/55, 8/11, 9/11, 49/55, 52/55, 54/55, 1}

```
Total[Range@10] Differences @ subDivide[{0, 1}, 10]
```

> {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one?

```
n = 2;
LineList = {{0, 0}, {5, 5}}
x1 = LineList[[2]]
x2 = LineList[[1]]
x = Reverse@FoldList[# + 1/(n*(n + 1)/2)*#2 (x2 - x1) &, x1, Range@n]
```

> {{0, 0}, {10/3, 10/3}, {5, 5}}

here is an example for

```
n = 10
LineList[{{0, 6}, {5, 25}}]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is the function you are asking for increasing intervals in [0,1]

```
F[n_, r_] := Accumulate@Join[{0}, Table[i*t + d, {i, 0, n - 1}]] /. 
Solve[((n - 1) t + d)/d == r && n*d + (n - 1) n/2 t == 1, {t, d}]
```

for example for n=5 and r=4 we get

```
F[5,4]
```

> {{0, 2/25, 11/50, 21/50, 17/25, 1}}

which matches your example

Comment: While this algorithm does the job for a case where n=ratio, I would like to have a more general one, where the ratio of the longest section to the shortest section and the number of divisionsn are not the same. So that on an interval of [0,1], using n=2 and ratio=4, I would get {0,4/5,1}. For n=2 the algorithm is quite simple, but for more than 2 division, I do not know how to handle this.